# Failure to execute javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error in console log:
[image]

Basically, the reset button isn't resetting the colors of the other buttons as I want it to. But it resets the first click me button instead:

[image]

[image]

The specific error is:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('[object HTMLButtonElement]') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.`

I'm dealing with code for Challenge 4, so in the HTML it starts at div container-4 and in the javascript it starts from //Challenge 4.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Static/style.css"
    <title>Javascript Challenges</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-1">
<h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>
<div class="flex-box-container-1">

<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div>
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-box-container-1">
    <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
</div>

<div class="container-2">
    <h2>Cat Generator</h2>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="cat-generator" onclick="generateCat()">Generate Cat</button>
    <div class="flex-box-container-2" id="flex-cat-gen">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-3">
<h2>Rock Paper Scissors</h2>
<div class= "flex-box-rps" id="flex-box-rps-div">

<img id="rock" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/49/a6/e9/49a6e9c659b49cf1f90909f79efde5b6.jpg" height=150 width=150 onclick="rpsGame(this)">
<img id="paper" src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/32/4a/74/324a74fe7d44c6d0a3bed47502277b61.jpg" height=150 width=150 onclick="rpsGame(this)" >
<img id="scissors" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Pair_of_scissors_with_black_handle%2C_2015-06-07.jpg/1200px-Pair_of_scissors_with_black_handle%2C_2015-06-07.jpg" height=150 width=150 onclick="rpsGame(this)">
</div>
</div>



<div class="container-4">

    <h2 id="change-my-colour">Change the colour of the buttons</h2>

<div class="flex-box-pick-colour">


<form action="">

    <select name="backdrop" id="background" onchange="buttonColourChange(this)">
    
<option value="random">Random</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="reset">Reset</option>

    </select>

</form>


<button class="btn btn-primary">Wee!</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Yahoo!</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning">Google!</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">Facebook!</button>

</div>



</div>


<script src ="static/script.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
.container-1 {border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 75%;
text-align: center;}


.flex-box-container-1 {border: 1px solid black;
display: flex;
padding: 10px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-direction: row;}

.flex-box-container-1 div {padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
align-items: center;}

.container-2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex-box-container-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}


.flex-box-container-2 img {
   margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
} 

.flex-box-rps img:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px blue;

}

.container-3 {border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;}

    .flex-box-rps {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .flex-box-pick-colour {border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        flex-direction: row;}

        .container-4 {border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 75%;
            text-align: center;}
```

```js
//Challenge 1: Age in Days

function ageInDays() 
{var birthYear = prompt('What year were you born?');
var ageInDayss = (2021 - birthYear) * 365;
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInDayss + ' days old');
h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageinDays');
h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);

}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById('flex-box-result').remove();}

//Challenge 2: Cat Generator 

    function generateCat() {
        var image = document.createElement ('img');
        var div = document.getElementById ('flex-cat-gen');
        image.src = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?/format=src&type=gif&size=small";
        div.appendChild(image);

    }

//Challenge 3: Rock, Paper, Scissors     

function rpsGame(yourChoice) {
    console.log(yourChoice);
    var humanChoice, botChoice;
    humanChoice = yourChoice.id;
    botChoice = numberToChoice(randToRpsInt());
    console.log('computer choice', botChoice);
     results = decideWinner(humanChoice, botChoice,); // [0, 1] human lost | bot won
     console.log(results);
    message = finalMessage(results); // {'message': 'You won', 'color': 'green'}
    console.log(message);
    rpsFrontEnd(yourChoice.id, botChoice, message);
}

function randToRpsInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

}

function numberToChoice(number) {
    return ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'] [number];
}

function decideWinner(yourChoice, computerChoice) {
    var rpsDataBase = {
        'rock': {'scissors': 1, 'rock': 0.5, 'paper': 0},
        'paper': {'scissors': 0, 'rock': 1, 'paper': 0.5},
        'scissors': {'scissors': 0.5, 'rock': 0, 'paper': 1}
    }

var yourScore = rpsDataBase[yourChoice] [computerChoice];
var computerScore = rpsDataBase[computerChoice] [yourChoice];
return [yourScore, computerScore];


    }

    function finalMessage([yourScore, computerScore]) {
    if (yourScore === 0) { return {'message': 'You lost', 'color': 'red'} }
    else if (yourScore === 0.5) {return {'message': 'Draw', 'color': 'yellow'}}
    else {return {'message': 'You won', 'color': 'green'}}
    
    
    

    }

    function rpsFrontEnd(humanImageChoice, botImageChoice, finalMessage)
    {
        var imagesDataBase = {
            'rock': document.getElementById('rock').src,
            'paper': document.getElementById('paper').src,
            'scissors': document.getElementById('scissors').src
        }

        document.getElementById('rock').remove();
        document.getElementById('paper').remove();
        document.getElementById('scissors').remove();

        var humanDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var botDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var messageDiv = document.createElement('div');

    humanDiv.innerHTML = "<img src= '" + imagesDataBase[humanImageChoice] + "' height=150 width=150'>"
    messageDiv.innerHTML = "<h1 style='color: " + finalMessage['color'] + "; font-size: 60px; padding: 30px; '>" + finalMessage['message'] + "</h1>"
    botDiv.innerHTML = "<img src= '" + imagesDataBase[botImageChoice] + "' height=150 width=150'>"
   
    
    document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(humanDiv);
    document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(botDiv);
    document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(messageDiv);
    }

//Challenge 4: Changing button colours

var all_Buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');


var copyAllButtons = [];
for (let i=0; i < all_Buttons.length; i++) {
    copyAllButtons.push(all_Buttons[i]);
}



function buttonColourChange(buttonThingy) {
    if (buttonThingy.value === 'red') {
        buttonsRed();

    } else if (buttonThingy.value === 'green') {
        buttonsGreen();
    } else if (buttonThingy.value === 'reset') {
        buttonColorReset();
    } else if (buttonThingy.value === 'random') {
        randomColors();
    }
}

function buttonsRed() {
    for (let i=0; i < all_Buttons.length; i++) {
        all_Buttons[i].classList.remove(all_Buttons[i].classList[1]);
        all_Buttons[i].classList.add('btn-danger');
    }
}

function buttonsGreen() {
    for (let i=0; i < all_Buttons.length; i++) {
        all_Buttons[i].classList.remove(all_Buttons[i].classList[1]);
        all_Buttons[i].classList.add('btn-success');
    }
}

function buttonColorReset() {
    for (let i=0; i < all_Buttons.length; i++) {
        all_Buttons[i].classList.remove(all_Buttons[i].classList[1]);
        all_Buttons[i].classList.add(copyAllButtons[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `copyAllButtons.push(all_Buttons[i]);` <-- you are pushing an DOM element to the array. and somehow you are using DOM element for a class? `all_Buttons[i].classList.add(copyAllButtons[i]);`

Comment: Hi, I'll be honest with you, I'm  new and I'm just following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qqx_wzMmFeA&t) (about 4 hrs 15 mins and onwards) so I've just copied along. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: turns out you were correct but I had absolutely no idea what you meant! but you pointed me in the right direction, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

my bad. I missed the following in line 108 of the javascript: copyAllButtons.push(all_Buttons[i].classList[1]);